# Python board game with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Im trying to create a python game that the player would click the board to fill it with their colors until it is complete, wins whoever has more filled boxes.
If you click a box and any adjacent box is filled with the other player color, it will change the color to yours, i found this board code but i cant get it to fill the adjacent boxes.

```
import Tkinter as tk

board = [ [None]*10 for _ in range(10) ]

counter = 0

root = tk.Tk()

def on_click(i,j,event):
    global counter
    color = "green" if counter%2 else "red"
    event.widget.config(bg=color)
    board[i][j] = color
    counter += 1


for i,row in enumerate(board):
    for j,column in enumerate(row):
        L = tk.Label(root,text='    ',bg='grey')
        L.grid(row=i,column=j,padx='3',pady='3')
        L.bind('<Button-1>',lambda e i=i,j=j: on_click(i,j,e))

root.mainloop()
```

**QUESTION:** How can i make it so when a player clicks a box the adjacent boxes that are already filled with  the enemy's color also turns red/green? Also how can i count the number of filled boxes with certain color to determine who won? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This took a while! Here's my version:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import TkMessageBox as messagebox

board = [ [None]*10 for _ in range(10) ]

counter = 0
root = tk.Tk()

def check_board():
    freespaces = 0
    redspaces = 0
    greenspaces = 0
    for i,row in enumerate(board):
        for j,column in enumerate(row):
            if board[i][j] == "red":
                redspaces += 1
            elif board[i][j] == "green":
                greenspaces += 1
            elif board[i][j] == None:
                freespaces += 1

    if freespaces == 0:
        if greenspaces > redspaces:
            winner = "green"
        elif greenspaces < redspaces:
            winner = "red"
        else:
            winner = "draw"

        if winner != "draw":
            messagebox.showinfo("Game Over!",winner+" wins!")
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("Game Over!","The game was a draw!")




def on_click(i,j,event):
    global counter
    if counter < 100:
        if board[i][j] == None:
            color = "green" if counter%2 else "red"
            enemycolor = "red" if counter%2 else "green"
            event.widget.config(bg=color)
            board[i][j] = color
            for k in range(-1,2):
                for l in range(-1,2):
                    try:
                        if board[i+k][j+l] == enemycolor:
                            board[i+k][j+l] = color
                    except IndexError:
                        pass
            counter += 1
            global gameframe
            gameframe.destroy()
            redraw()
            root.wm_title(enemycolor+"'s turn")
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("Alert","This square is already occupied!")
        check_board()


def redraw():
    global gameframe
    gameframe = tk.Frame(root)
    gameframe.pack()

    for i,row in enumerate(board):

        for j,column in enumerate(row):
            name = str(i)+str(j)
            L = tk.Label(gameframe,text='    ',bg= "grey" if board[i][j] == None else board[i][j])
            L.grid(row=i,column=j,padx='3',pady='3')
            L.bind('<Button-1>',lambda e,i=i,j=j:on_click(i,j,e))


redraw()
root.mainloop()
```

I'm redrawing the whole board each time, as there's no stored reference to the widgets. I can't see a way to access each widget after they've been created because they're all called "L", so I check the board for colour values and create the widgets based on if they're colored. Checking is done by looking at the colours in the 3x3 grid around the square.

I added a function to check the squares and then detect if they're all full, you should be able to work out what's happening by studying the code, if you have any questions let me know. A nice touch I added is to change the title bar based on who's turn it is!

edit: To add a label notifying the current player's colour, add the following to the end of your redraw function!

```
global counter
whosturn = "Green" if counter%2 else "Red"
turnLbl = tk.Label(gameframe,text=color+"'s Turn")
turnLbl.grid(row=11,column = 0,columnspan = 10)
```

Comment: Thanks for help! I have a question. Would be possible to put the warn of what player turn it is on top of the board as a label instead of in the window or it would need the board to be re-coded and to create a class? Im confused with the way the board is created.

Comment: yup! updated answer, add the last part to the redraw function. Ideally you should recreate the whole program from scratch, and properly code it in a class to learn more. It's a lot better to pass variables around using self. and Tk vars rather than using messy global variables.

Answer (score 2):

If you store the labels in `board`, then you can access its background color with

```
board[i][j]['bg']
```

and you can change the background color with

```
board[i][j].config(bg=...)
```

or even

```
board[i][j]['bg'] = ...
```

---

Since you want to access the neighbors of a point on the `board`, it is natural to use `for-loop`s such as:

```
for ii in range(i - 1, i + 2):
    for jj in range(j - 1, j + 2):
```

or, equivalently but with less nesting use [itertools.product](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
import itertools as IT
for ii, jj in IT.product(range(i - 1, i + 2), range(j - 1, j + 2)):
```

Now you can access the neighbor with `board[ii][jj]`, bearing in mind that `ii` or `jj` might be an out-of-bounds index. We can deal with out-of-bounds indices by using an `if`-statement:

```
if ii<0 or ii>=rows or jj<0 or jj>=cols: continue
```

---

Putting to use the two ideas above, 
you can count the number of red, green and grey squares using a [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
import collections
collections.Counter(
        board[i][j]['bg'] for i, j in IT.product(range(rows), range(cols)))
```

---

```
import Tkinter as tk
import itertools as IT
import collections

cols, rows = 3, 3
board = [[None] * cols for _ in range(rows)]    
other = {'green': 'red', 'red': 'green'}

player = 'red'   

def on_click(event, i, j):
    global player
    board[i][j]['bg'] = player
    for ii, jj in IT.product(range(i - 1, i + 2), range(j - 1, j + 2)):
        if ii<0 or ii>=rows or jj<0 or jj>=cols: continue
        neighbor = board[ii][jj]
        if neighbor['bg'] != 'grey' and (ii, jj) != (i, j):
            neighbor['bg'] = other[neighbor['bg']]
    check_for_winner()
    player = other[player]

def check_for_winner():
    s = score()
    if s['red'] + s['green'] == cols*rows:
        # every box filled
        winner = max(s, key=s.get)
        print('Winner is: {}'.format(winner))
        root.after(1, flash_winner, winner, 'blue')

def score():
    return collections.Counter(
        board[i][j]['bg'] for i, j in IT.product(range(rows), range(cols)))

def flash_winner(winner, altcolor):
    for i, j in IT.product(range(rows), range(cols)):
        if board[i][j]['bg'] == winner:
            board[i][j]['bg'] = altcolor
    root.after(250, flash_winner, altcolor, winner)

root = tk.Tk()
for i, j in IT.product(range(rows), range(cols)):
    board[i][j] = L = tk.Label(root, text='    ', bg='grey')
    L.grid(row=i, column=j, padx=3, pady=3)
    L.bind('<Button-1>', lambda e, i=i, j=j: on_click(e, i, j))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now i'll have to study some of the things you used to understand.